# Modular iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, modular, extensible

I'm considering a way to make an easy extensible iOS app. Let me explain, a client want's an app which is easy extensible with modules, so we can make separate modules and add them as wished to a base app. It have to be a possibility to make de modules in a new Xcode Project (it may be that inheritance of an interface is necessary). So in the end, de modules have to be added tot the Xcode Project of the base app and the new added module (UIView) is automatically added to the tab bar menu (or any other menu structure).

I'm not asking for code snippets but just your opinion of how to solve this problem or what the best way is to do it.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: I have an open source modularization framework in iOS named TinyPart, may can help you learn something about modularization in iOS. https://github.com/RyanLeeLY/TinyPart

Comment: Thanks @yaoli I will check your repository!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to develop a framework. Find the pieces of the app that you want to be shared among other apps. Make that into its own, standalone entity.
On my projects, I have similar apps with different UI's. So the core of how data is retrieved and manipulated is all the same code. What differs is the UI.

That's the approach I would take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking now for how to use frameworks in Xcode, it seems to be an easy thing. But because of I have different views as modules how can I link an .xib file with the code behind it to a framework? In other words my modules (frameworks) have to be views.